# Help Us improve the site - broken link - old blog post

Tags: support, status-completed, review, blog, broken-link

Broken Link on the Review page on Stack Overflow

Steps to reproduce:

- go to Stack Overflow
- click the review link on the top
- find the yellow banner on the right

[image: right-side banner]

- click the link 'you' (pointing to https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- receive a message that the link is no longer found and that you can report a broken link on the feedback site (meta)

Comment: [The devs have been pinged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303496/answer-your-own-question-faq-links-broken#comment238494_303496). Several blog posts seems broken now....